# Does "made a curse" in Gal 3:13 k.J.V mean "made cursed"?

Tags: galatians, kjv, curses

First of all, I would like you not to consider what I am going to say as blasphemy. I'd like to know the nature of christhood. I am trying to know what actually happened, without any bias. What the hermeneutic tells me I shall follow.

In Gal 3:13 (KJV):

> "being made a curse for us",

Look: 1 Corinthians 12:3 (KJV):

> 3. Wherefore I give you to understand, that no man speaking by the Spirit of God calleth **Jesus accursed:** and {cf15I that} no man can say that Jesus is the Lord, but by the Holy Ghost.

**does "made a curse" mean "made cursed"?**. If so, why not sin=sinner in 2 Corinthians 5:21:

> "made him {cf15I to be} sin for us" K.J.v?

I think linguistically and logically since **curse=cursed**, so: **sin=sinner**. Thus, made him to be **sin** for us, is interpreted as: made him to be **sinner** for us.

Why in 2 Corinthians 5:16 Paul says:

> "yea, though we have known Christ after the flesh, yet now henceforth know we {cf15I him} no more."

Look:

- Luke 13:32 (KJV):

> 32. And he said unto them, Go ye, and tell that fox, Behold, I cast out devils, and I do cures to day and to morrow, **and the third {cf15I day} I shall be perfected.**

2 Corinthians 13:4 (KJV):

> 4. For though **he was crucified through weakness,** yet he liveth by the power of God. For we also are weak in him, but we shall live with him by the power of God toward you.

- Hebrews 2:10 (KJV):

> 10. For it became him, for whom {cf15I are} all things, and by whom {cf15I are} all things, in bringing many sons unto glory, to **make the captain of their salvation perfect through sufferings.**

- Hebrews 5:9 (KJV):

> 9. **And being made perfect**, he became the author of eternal salvation unto all them that obey him;

- Hebrews 7:28 (ASV):

> 28. For the law appointeth men high priests, having infirmity; but the word of the oath, which was after the law, {**cf15i appointeth} a Son, perfected for evermore.**

I think Jesus must resembles us in everything even inclination to sin, but he exceeds us in Will and Faith, hence by Will and Faith he overcame the Sin, Look: Hebrews 12:2.

Hebrews 12:2 (ASV):

> 2. looking unto **Jesus the author and perfecter of {cf15i our} faith,** who for the joy that was set before him endured the cross, despising shame, and hath sat down at the right hand of the throne of God.

So, his mission is to teach us how to overcome the Sin by the Act of Will and Faith.

So, **does "made a curse" in Gal 3:13 (KJV) mean "made cursed"?**

Comment: The original [TR] of the KJV reads γενομενος υπερ ημων καταρα. Literally [EGNT] this translates _having become for us a curse._ Or, having become on our behalf a curse. It is better if you confine to one question at a time on Stack Exchange. The voting model is designed only to cope with one at a time. Your second question about  Corinthians 5:16 is a different subject.

Comment: @NigelJ 2 Corinthians 5:16 has intimate relationship to the question, since being in flesh means liable to Sin.

Comment: What evidence do you have for that statement ? (That merely being in flesh means 'having an inclination to sin' or being 'liable to sin'.) 'Sin came into the world' Romans 5:12 via a created spirit, a serpentine spirit. Sin, true, is _associated_ with flesh but sin itself is spiritual. For he was 'made' sin (2 Corinthians 5:21) : which was a spiritual act. [But I am not voting to close, it was just a suggestion.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be made a curse = to be cursed. Christ is no longer hanging on a tree. He was buried then resurrected. Now He's God in His humanity. He was already God in man, but now His humanity is 'officially' in the Godhead, Rm 1:4. To be made sin on our behalf is to be counted as sin, treated as sin. Jesus Christ wasn't a sinner experientially. Nor was He treated as 'a sinner' by God. Rather He was and is the Lamb of God, who takes away the sin of the whole world---whoever accepts that gift of righteous legal forgiveness from God. (Which is permanent by the way. There's no way of losing or giving back that gift...eternally.) To be made a curse is by (judicial) act of another. Likewise to be made sin, 'sin' and 'a curse' both being nouns. To be 'made a sinner,' though, would be to be made something not merely by law, but organically. That is, interiorly. Subjectively.

Comment: to fall in Sin is to be actually a Sinner, Since you already committed a Sin. BUT, if you resisted the Sin, not surrendered to Sin, tried to give up the act of Sin then you aren't Sinner. You have some weaknesses, but you are not a Sinner. I think this was the Case of Christ.

Comment: dear Salah, I would say come to Him and ask Him all these questions....about His Book, if you haven't already. "Give up the act..." in English means that you already did the act. God became weak in order to become executed, crucified. 2 Cor 13:4. And He was meek, as a lamb led to the slaughter, where God, through fallen man's action, slaughtered Him for mankind. But in Him, the god of this age "had nothing." Jn 14:30